# How to fetch parameters from a GET request in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, chatbot, rasa-core

So I have been building a chatbot powered by RASA stack (open source).
After creating the bot, I wanted to integrate it with our web application. Now I'm able get responses from my RASA core but I'm in a problem. I'm passing a unique user_id in the GET request which i need to fetch inside a python function and call an external API to my Database. But I don't know how to fetch that parameter out from GET request. here are some details.

My `GET` request: (I uploaded my bot on AWS server)
http://my_ip_.amazonaws.com:5005/conversations/27/respond?q=%27Hi

So my unique id is `27` which i want to fetch inside a python function.

and the response i'm getting by this request :

```
[{“recipient_id”:“27”,“text”:“Hey! What can I do for you?”}]
```

As you can see I passed the GET request in postman and got this response from my RASA CHATBOT but I want to track this user-id 27.

So my question is how can I track this id? Or maybe you guys can suggest me another way to do it.

Thanks for your help in advance :) My first post BTW :)

[Please ask me anything if you feel this question is missing something]

Comment: `id = response[0]['recipient_id']`, is this not working fine?

Comment: @sid8491 No it didn't.

Comment: thats interesting, logically it should work. you should check the response type, and parse it accordingly. @Arseniy has written below both cases if its an array or dictionary. try that and let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I solved this issue by using tracker data. Actually, I had to link tracker dictionary to my custom action file so that I can access the sender_id and other slot values.
I used:

```
user_id = tracker.sender_id
parameters ={}
parameters = {"user_id": user_id}
```

then it follows by my post request and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you are receiving the following data from the request:
`[{“recipient_id”:“27”,“text”:“Hey! What can I do for you?”}]`.
If it's a list:
just use:

`response = [{“recipient_id”:“27”,“text”:“Hey! What can I do for you?”}]
recepient_id = response[0]['recipient_id']`

If it's a dict:

`response = {“recipient_id”:“27”,“text”:“Hey! What can I do for you?”}
recepient_id = response['recipient_id']`

Comment: Yeah so consider this we have a bot widget in our site whenever user opens the widget and says "Hi" a GET request is called to my RASA aws server and I return back the response. So this response is on my web app not in my rasa. So when a request comes my bot initiates a custom action which is nothing but a python scripts with some API's. So i need to save this id in some variable so that i can pass that id to API

Comment: @Akshitjain you should mention this detail in the question, it will help people to understand what exactly is happening

Comment: @Arseniy No i'm not receiving that response. that response is going to my web app server for chat bot to answer. I'm receiving this GET request with a query and an user_id. I want to fetch this id. See when I call from web server for hi , i'll get a response from RASA based on this query. So i'm able to parse that query give back a suitable answer by nlu.